# Trait and Implementation vs just Implementation

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, scala

In my previous Java job, we tended to avoid defining interfaces for everything unless we genuinely had multiple implementations for it. This may just be my opinion, but if there is only one implementation, I don't see the value in an interface - we're not really writing generic code, that might be used as a library.

However, in my new Scala job we tend to use traits everywhere - lots of things like, DAOs or 'Service' classes, will have a trait that defines what they do at the top of the file and then the only implementation beneath it.

e.g.

```
trait WidgetDAO {
    getAllWidgets(): Seq[Widget]
}
class RealWidgetDAO extends WidgetDAO {
    getAllWidgets(): Seq[Widget] {
        // ...
```

I'm new to Scala so is there any Scala-specific reason why this style is common in our codebase? Or is it the more generic "Code to interfaces" rule of thumb that's driving this, somewhat unnecessarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particular reason why Scala traits should be treated differently than Java interfaces, especially if the trait is interface-like and only requires certain methods.

One important difference is that traits can also provide method implementations (although Java 8 default methods can also kind of do that). This leads to a somewhat different programming style where it makes to implement some methods in a separate trait for clarity.

This use of traits is less like an interface and more like a partial class. When using traits as the unit of code composition, you can reason about and test each trait with its cohesive set of methods independently. This tends to be better (clearer, more maintainable, more testable) than putting many weakly related methods into a single large class.

The primary reason to use interfaces (and interface-like traits) is that you want to do polymorphism. In your particular example – a DAO – this seems very desirable so that you can use mock DAO implementations for tests. If you don't need polymorphisms and these interfaces do not provide any useful functionality (like only a single methods that cannot be used on its own), then that might be a case of interface overuse.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it the more generic "Code to interfaces" rule of thumb that's driving this, somewhat unnecessarily?

Yes, this is just a "code to interfaces" rule.

> is there any Scala-specific reason why this style is common in our codebase?

No, it is entirely orthogonal to use of Scala; if I had to guess, I would be pretty sure that such separation is *more* popular in Java.

Comment: this reads more like a comment, see [answer]

Comment: Why? This is a direct answer to the 2 questions asked in the last paragraph. Yes, it's short; it doesn't need to be long.

Comment: well even after the recent edit it looks rather poor to me, like merely expressing a personal opinion without attempting to back it up somehow (particularly when compared against another answer that was posted several hours earlier than this one)